# parseInt возвращает неправильное значение

Tags: javascript

```
parseInt(16, 2)
```

Этот код вернет 1. Почему? Я был уверен что вернется NaN! Так как 6 не валидное значение.

Comment: "Так как 6 не валидное значение." --- а причём тут 6 ? и почему оно невалидное?

Comment: Как я понял, функция parseInt переводит из base 2 в base 10. Число 16 не может быть в base 2, так как есть число 6. Я ожидаю вывода NaN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из **[доков](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)**

> Если функция `parseInt` встречает символ, не являющийся числом в указанной системе счисления, она пропускает этот и все последующие символы (даже, если они подходящие) и возвращает целое число, преобразованное из части строки, предшествовавшей этому символу.

То есть 1 в системе исчисления "2" - подошла, дальше 6 - не подошло, её пропускает и следующие за ней тоже.

Comment: Спасибо! Есть ли идеи как я могу перевести число из 2 в 10 отсеивая невалдиные значения? :)

Comment: @Alexey из 2  в 10? об этом на информатике обычно говорят как))  .......... а если в строке есть что-то не равное 0 или 1 - это не двоичное число.

Comment: Понял, понял! Просто думал, вдруг есть какая нибудь супер функция :), которая делает это за меня!

Comment: @Alexey ну написанных-то полно. Их просто поискать. Встроенную в js - не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

В документации написано:

> string
>
> Значение, которое необходимо проинтерпретировать. Если значение
> параметра string не принадлежит строковому типу, оно преобразуется в
> него (с помощью абстрактной операции ToString). Пробелы в начале
> строки не учитываются.

```
x = 16;
y = x.toString(); // получится '16'
z = parseInt(y, 2); // равносильно parseInt('16', 2) и выдаст 1
```

потому что все символы от символа не из словаря системы счисления ('0', '1') будут отброшены

```
parseInt('11ax1', 2) // = 3, потому что будет проанализировано только `11`
```

Опять же из указанной ссылки:

> Если функция parseInt встречает символ, не являющийся числом в
> указанной системе счисления, она пропускает этот и все последующие
> символы (даже, если они подходящие) и возвращает целое число,
> преобразованное из части строки, предшествовавшей этому символу.
> parseInt отсекает дробную часть числа. Пробелы в начале и конце строки
> разрешены.